# Navigation Drawer stays open

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I'm working on a c# WPF program and i've a Navigation Drawer that should be closed when a checkBox is checked and opened when the checkbox is not checked

Here is a Screenshot from the Navigation Drawer

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpOOn.png]

I'm trying to do that with a DataTrigger.

Here is the XAML Code:

My Storyboards:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Width)"
                From="70"
                To="350"
                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Width)"
                From="350"
                To="70"
                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And the DataTrigger:

```
<Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
```

And the CheckBox

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBox" />
```

The problem is that the Navigation Drawer stays open.
It closes quickly and opens again when I check the CheckBox.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This is the code after BionicCode's answer:

```
<Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="70" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}" />
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
```

Comment: You should merge both triggers. Only trigger on `IsChecked=True` and open the menu using the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` property and close it using the `DataTrigger.ExitActions`. This should solve the problem. The `DataTrigger.ExitActions` will be executed once the triggering property loses its trigger state i.e. has changed to `False`.

Comment: @BionicCode very nice! it's works, thank you!